# In Google Sheets, how can I use one IF statement to compare a date & time to multiple date ranges?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Bit of a wordy way to ask the question, but couldn't think of a shorter alternative.

I'm trying to make a sheet where I can put start/end times for individual people, and have it check a spreadsheet that shows when they're unavailable. An example of what the unavailability sheet looks like is shown here, with their name on the left hand side (column C), and the start/end of their unavailability on the middle (column D) and right (column E) respectively.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8sgQ.png)

In another sheet (the one where I put start and end times) I have this function. In this, B17 is a start time (for example "15:30"), B2 is the date and A17 is the name (in this case "Mike"):
`=IF(B17="","No",IF(AND(B$2+B17>=FILTER('Unavailability Form'!$D$2:$D$116,'Unavailability Sheet'!$C$2:$C$116=$A17),B$2+B17<=FILTER('Unavailability Form'!$E$2:$E$116,'Unavailability Sheet'!$C$2:$C$116=$A17)),"Yes","No"))`

When running the function I currently have, it only seems to check the first result for a name in the unavailability form, rather than all three I currently have. Is there a way to change the above function to allow it to check all the date & time periods instead of the first one in the list?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Made a copy of the sheet I'm using and removed personal info so I can share here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17wUwvVh55p7VRjLUzm4YrKdJT4LhE4nluar9k8iOdrI/edit?usp=sharing

EDIT 2: Changed the link as the edit history showed personal info.

Comment: Please include text based examples in your questions. Sharing an editable sheet could help.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(
   LET(range,'Other Unavailability'!A2:C,
     start,B34, end,E34, _date,B33, name,"Mike",
     nm,INDEX(rng,,1), st,INDEX(rng,,2), et,INDEX(rng,,3), 
     SUMPRODUCT(nm=name, INT(st)=_date, 
       (MOD(st,1)>=start)*(MOD(st,1)<=end)+
       (MOD(et,1)>=start)*(MOD(et,1)<=end)+
       NOT(LEN(end))*(MOD(et,1)>=start))),
   "Yes", "No")
```

## Tests

1. **`nm=name`**               (name matches),
   **AND**
2. **`INT(st)=_date`**   (date matches),
   **AND**
3. Any of the following:

   1. **`(MOD(st,1)>=start)*(MOD(st,1)<=end)`**
      ('Other Unavailability' start time is between start and end)
      **OR**
   2. **`(MOD(et,1)>=start)*(MOD(et,1)<=end)`**
      ('Other Unavailability' end time is between start and end)
      **OR**
   3. **`NOT(LEN(end))*(MOD(et,1)>=start)))`**
      ('Other Unavailability' end time is after start and end is blank/empty)